# How to use middleware in Nextjs 13?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to use middleware in Nextjs by creating a file called middleware.js at the root of my project (same level as my pages folder).

Inside the file, I have something simple like this:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(request) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/about-2', request.url))
}
```

But when I run the localhost, it gives me this error:

```
error - Error [TypeError]: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/file.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:5724:19)
    at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
    at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/formdata.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:5881:49)
    at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
    at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:6094:35)
    at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
    at ../../node_modules/.pnpm/undici@5.11.0/node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/response.js (evalmachine.<anonymous>:6510:49)
    at __require (evalmachine.<anonymous>:14:50)
    at <unknown> (evalmachine.<anonymous>:11635:30)
    at requireFn (file://C:\Users\username\Desktop\Nextjs-Blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\edge-runtime\index.js:1:7079) {
  middleware: true
}
```

So im just wondering if Im doing anything wrong with that code? I used the same thing for my previous project (nextjs 12) and everything seems fine, only this project when I tried Nextjs 13 that it happen.

Comment: I think the code is correct.
What version of Node JS are you using?
You will need node.js 16.8 or higher to use Next.js 13

Comment: oh i see, I was using node 14. thank you @ArianHamdi

Comment: @ArianHamdi please create an answer so it can be solved. And for the OP: also accept it, if it solves the problem.